# Replace div with regex

Tags: php, regex

i need to replace all div's containig class "ta" and id "ta_somenumber" with textareas that will keep same attributes. Here is example code:

```
$html_content = '<div class="ta" id="ta_345">sometext</div><span style="...">Some text</span><--!more html--><div class="ta" id="ta_5687">sometext</div>';
```

Here is what i want to achieve:

```
$html_new_content = '<textarea class="ta" id="ta_345">sometext</textarea><span style="...">Some text</span><--!more html--><textarea class="ta" id="ta_5687">sometext</textarea>';
```

I was trying with this:

```
$regex1 = '#\<div class=\"ta\" id=\"(.*)\"\>(.+?)\<\/div\>#s';
$regex2 = '#\<textarea class=\"ta\" id=\"(.*)\"\>(.+?)\<\/textarea\>#s';

$result = str_replace($regex2, $regex3, $html_content);
```

But for some reason this doesnt work. I tried with preg_replace but no luck.

Comment: Just a note that it's bad practice to try to parse HTML using regex, as HTML is not a regular language. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one regex, and that would look like this:

```
$regex = '#<div class="ta" id="([^"]+)">(.+?)</div>#s';
$result = preg_replace( $regex, 
    '<textarea class="ta" id="$1">$2</textarea>', 
    $html_content
);
```

This finds all of the `<div>` tags, capturing their ID attributes in backreference #1 and their content in backreference #2. Then, the replacement is simple: Replace the `<div>` with a `<textarea>` that has the "ta" class and the same ID and contents as the original `<div>`.

You can see it working in [the demo](http://viper-7.com/mA1x7X).

Comment: But only if the `class` and `id` attribute are always ordered the same way, seperated by a single space, uses `"` and not `'` to delimit the attribute values, there are no other attributes etc... @SomeoneS : you should rather create a tree / DOM and change the attributes there.